# OpenCart 2.3.0.2, meta title changed to "Hacked by TheWayEnd"

Tags: opencart

"Hacked by TheWayEnd", into **Settings > Server** the error log was changed to twe.php and the new file tew.php also created.

Comment: I would look at your apache log for clues. Or, sanitize it of your IP and any other identifying info and post it online for people to review, as this sounds potentially serious!

Answer (score 1):

Things I will suggest

1. Use HTTPS for both the admin and frontend
2. Choose a reliable hosting provider
3. Avoid using dictionary words as password

Comment: Much better answer than mine - I jumped to the worst case scenario :)

Answer (score 1):

Also prevent executing php outside the Opencart framework. Add this to your **.htaccess**:

```
<FilesMatch ".*\.php$">
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost
</FilesMatch>
<Files index.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```